# when i run rvm install 2.0.0 in terminal it shows the following error

Tags: ruby

Command `head` is available in `/usr/bin/head`
The command could not be located because `/usr/bin` is not included in the `PATH` environment variable.

> head: command not found

Command `sort` is available in `/usr/bin/sort`
The command could not be located because `/usr/bin` is not included in the `PATH` environment variable.

> sort: command not found

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Then run:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

and try again.

Comment: Why are you certain that OP uses `bash`?

Comment: @mudasobwa instincts.